# Issue in replacing content through fragment in naviagtion drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a framelayout in which there are several child, but when I replace it with fragment it doesn't replace it instead it overlaps with the framelayout xml file. I have read some documentation but I'm unable find the right one.

a small help would be great. Thank you!

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_notification) {
            Fragment fragment = NotificationFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#bb4297f2"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.bulletin.theinvincible.nautical.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Hi Ashu, What does your yacht need today?"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button

                android:background="@drawable/button_round"
                android:id="@+id/button_bookslip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Book a Slip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_hireCaptain"
                android:background="@drawable/button_round"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Hire a Captain" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_hireCrewMember"
                android:background="@drawable/button_round"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Hire a Crew Member" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_more"
                android:background="@drawable/button_round"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="More..." />

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:text="Provide Services to Boat Owners? Get Work Here" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s do not remove/replace anything not in a `Fragment`.

Comment: so what does it do

Comment: As the name itself suggests, it transacts `Fragment`s. Those `View`s you have inside that `FrameLayout` are not part of a `Fragment`'s `View`, so a `FragmentTransaction` won't do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_notification) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new NotificationFragment()).commit();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code should replace only the views inside content_frame with NotificationFragment. What problem are you actually facing ? Does the childs of content_frame remain even after replacing with fragment?